# Laravel 5-Execute sql statement in string

Tags: php, sql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5. 
I need to save some sql statements in a field of a table of the database (these statements are used to get some results).
I want to get these statements in my controller and execute them using Laravel, but the statements are only strings, 
Let's suppose the following

```
$statement = Table::where('ID', 1);
$statement = $statement->STATEMENT;
```

In $statement I have a string like this

```
$statement = 'SELECT SUM(VAL) FROM TABLE';
```

What I need to know is how to execute in the database the statement saved in my string var `$statement`
I finally want to have something like

```
$result = 10 (the result of executing 'SELECT SUM(VAL) FROM TABLE', which was in $statement)
```

Thanks!

Comment: So do you know how read the `statement` but dont how execute it?

Comment: Yeah, that is. I don't know how to execute my $statement :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called raw queries in laravel. For example:

```
DB::select(DB::raw('select * from users''));
```

So in your case(if You've already got `$statement`):

```
DB::select(DB::raw($statement));
```